# Indy HTTPS POST Request in Delphi using TLS 1.0 instead of TLS 1.2

Tags: delphi, indy

I'm trying to make an HTTPS Post request in Delphi XE6 and Indy (v10.6.2.0).

I was able to successfully perform the call to this API and get the response using JavaScript:

[JavaScript code causing API response to output twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65904578/)

But I need to do the same in a Delphi application.

I tried multiple attempts using various configurations with `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`, but am getting the error:

> Could not load SSL library

The `libeay32.dll` was the culprit. I also went to the GitHub repo for Indy and wasn't sure which dependent file I needed to download.

The code below is giving me the error:

> Cannot open file "C:\Users.. \IndyHTTPSTest\Win32\Debug\dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=". The system cannot find the file specified.

What am I missing to get this to run in Delphi XE6 like the JavaScript code?

I have included `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` within my project folder.

Here's my code:

```
unit uMainForm;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, IdBaseComponent, IdSSLOpenSSL, IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders,
  System.NetEncoding, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
    GetBtn: TButton;
    ResponseMemo: TMemo;
    procedure GetBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;
  ss: TStringStream;
  s, sLog, sFile : String;
  Base64: TBase64Encoding;
  Txt: TextFile;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Assign JSON to TStringStream
  ss := TStringStream.Create('locations= [{"address":"Test1","lat":"52.05429","lng":"4.248618"},{"address":"Test2","lat":"52.076892","lng":"4.26975"},{"address":"Test3","lat":"51.669946","lng":"5.61852"},{"address":"Sint-Oedenrode, The Netherlands","lat":"51.589548","lng":"5.432482"}]', TEncoding.UTF8);
  // Base64 encode username and password string to satisfy API for "Authorization", "Basic " + sLog);
  s := 'username:password';
  Base64 := TBase64Encoding.Create(20, '');
  sLog := Base64.Encode(s);
end;

procedure TMainForm.GetBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  responseFromServer, sWhichFail, sVer :string;
  LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(self);
  with LHandler do
    begin
      SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv2;
      SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
      SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
      SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
      host := '';
    end;

  IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create(Self);
  with IdHTTP1 do
    begin
      IOHandler := LHandler;
      AllowCookies := True;
      ProxyParams.BasicAuthentication := False;
      ProxyParams.ProxyPort := 0;
      Request.ContentLength := -1;
      Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
      Request.ContentRangeEnd := 0;
      Request.ContentRangeStart := 0;
      Request.Accept := 'text/json, */*';
      Request.BasicAuthentication := True;
      Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)';

      HTTPOptions := [hoForceEncodeParams];
    end;

    try
      // Set up the request and send it
        sFile:= IdHTTP1.Post('https://api.routexl.com/tour', sLog);
        ResponseMemo.Lines.Add(Format('Response Code: %d', [IdHTTP1.ResponseCode]));
        ResponseMemo.Lines.Add(Format('Response Text: %s', [IdHTTP1.ResponseText]));
    finally
      sWhichFail:= WhichFailedToLoad();
      ShowMessage(sWhichFail);
      ResponseMemo.Lines.Text:= sWhichFail;
      //sVer := OpenSSLVersion();
      //ShowMessage(sVer);
    end;
end;

end.
```

**UPDATE**: I have updated the code, and added screenshots to help with debugging:

```
unit uMainForm;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, IdBaseComponent, IdSSLOpenSSL, IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders,
  System.NetEncoding, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
    GetBtn: TButton;
    ResponseMemo: TMemo;
    procedure GetBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    sl: TStringList;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  sl.Add('locations=[{"address":"Test1","lat":"52.05429","lng":"4.248618"},{"address":"Test2","lat":"52.076892","lng":"4.26975"},{"address":"Test3","lat":"51.669946","lng":"5.61852"},{"address":"Sint-Oedenrode, The Netherlands","lat":"51.589548","lng":"5.432482"}]');
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  sl.Free;
end;

procedure TMainForm.GetBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  LHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  responseFromServer, sWhichFail, sVer :string;
begin
  ResponseMemo.Clear;

  LHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(LHTTP);
    LHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];
    LHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
    LHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
    LHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;

    LHTTP.IOHandler := LHandler;
    LHTTP.AllowCookies := True;
    LHTTP.Request.Accept := 'text/json, */*';
    LHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := True;
    LHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    LHTTP.Request.Username := 'username:';
    LHTTP.Request.Password := 'password';

    LHTTP.HTTPOptions := [hoForceEncodeParams];

    try
      responseFromServer := IdHTTP1.Post('https://api.routexl.com/tour', sl);
      ResponseMemo.Lines.Text := responseFromServer;
    except
      on E: EIdOSSLCouldNotLoadSSLLibrary do
      begin
        sVer := OpenSSLVersion();
        sWhichFail := WhichFailedToLoad();
        ResponseMemo.Lines.Add(sVer);
        ResponseMemo.Lines.Add(sWhichFail);
        ShowMessage('Could not load OpenSSL');
      end;
      on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
      begin
        ResponseMemo.Lines.Add(Format('Response Code: %d', [LHTTP.ResponseCode]));
        ResponseMemo.Lines.Add(Format('Response Text: %s', [LHTTP.ResponseText]));
        ResponseMemo.Lines.Add(E.ErrorMessage);
        ShowMessage('HTTP Failure');
      end;
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        ResponseMemo.Lines.Add(E.ClassName);
        ResponseMemo.Lines.Add(E.Message);
        ShowMessage('Unknown Error');
      end;
    end;
  finally
    LHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

WireShark is showing the following when executing the JavaScript code:

[image]

WireShark is showing the following when executing the Delphi code:

[image]

Comment: Obviously the second parameter of `Post()` is a file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get an OpenSSL load error from Indy, you can call Indy's `WhichFailedToLoad()` function in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit to find out why.  Which you are, but you didn't show us what it is actually saying, so we can't diagnose why OpenSSL is failing to load.  Typically, the load will fail because either:

- `libeay32.dll` and/or `ssleay32.dll` cannot be found.  If they are not in the same folder as your program, or at least on the OS' DLL search path, then you can use Indy's `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` function in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit to tell Indy where to look for them.
- they are a different bitness than your program.  A 32bit program cannot load 64bit DLLs, and vice versa.
- they are missing required exported functions, which would indicate that they are likely a version of OpenSSL that Indy simply does not support.  For instance, `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` supports only up to OpenSSL 1.0.2u.  For OpenSSL 1.1.x+, you need to use [this experimental `SSLIOHandler`](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/pull/299) instead.

With that said, I see several things wrong with your Post code:

- you are manually encoding input data that you don't need to encode manually at all.  `TIdHTTP.Post()` can handle that internally for you.
- you are calling the version of `TIdHTTP.Post()` that takes a `String` filename as input, which will open the specified file and send its content as-is.  But you are not passing in a filename, you are passing in your Base64-encoded *user credentials* (not even your *JSON*).  To make a proper `application/x-www-webform-urlencoded` post, you need to use the version of `TIdHTTP.Post()` that takes a `TStrings` of `name=value` pairs as input.
- `TIdHTTP` natively implements `Basic` authentication, so you should be using the `TIdHTTP.Request.UserName` and `TIdHTTP.Request.Password` properties for your user credentials.
- you are telling `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` to use SSL v2.0.  Nobody uses that anymore, as it is no longer secure.  You should not be using anything less than TLS v1.0 as an absolute minimum.  And even that is being phased out on most servers.  So make sure you also have TLS v1.1 and TLS v1.1 enabled, too (for TLS v1.3, you need to use the [other `SSLIOHandler`](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/pull/299)).

Frankly, your Delphi code is not even close to replicating what the Javascript code is doing.  Try something more like this instead:

```pascal
unit uMainForm;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, IdBaseComponent, IdSSLOpenSSL, IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders,
  System.NetEncoding, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    GetBtn: TButton;
    ResponseMemo: TMemo;
    procedure GetBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    sl: TStringList;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  sl.Add('locations=[{"address":"Test1","lat":"52.05429","lng":"4.248618"},{"address":"Test2","lat":"52.076892","lng":"4.26975"},{"address":"Test3","lat":"51.669946","lng":"5.61852"},{"address":"Sint-Oedenrode, The Netherlands","lat":"51.589548","lng":"5.432482"}]');
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  sl.Free;
end;

procedure TMainForm.GetBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  LHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  responseFromServer, sWhichFail, sVer :string;
begin
  ResponseMemo.Clear;

  LHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(LHTTP);
    LHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
    LHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
    LHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
    LHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;

    LHTTP.IOHandler := LHandler;
    LHTTP.AllowCookies := True;
    LHTTP.Request.Accept := 'text/json, */*';
    LHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := True;
    LHTTP.Request.Username := 'username';
    LHTTP.Request.Password := 'password';

    LHTTP.HTTPOptions := [hoForceEncodeParams];

    try
      responseFromServer := IdHTTP1.Post('https://api.routexl.com/tour', sl);
      ResponseMemo.Lines.Text := responseFromServer;
    except
      on E: EIdOSSLCouldNotLoadSSLLibrary do
      begin
        sVer := OpenSSLVersion();
        sWhichFail := WhichFailedToLoad();
        ResponseMemo.Lines.Add(sVer);
        ResponseMemo.Lines.Add(sWhichFail);
        ShowMessage('Could not load OpenSSL');
      end;
      on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
      begin
        ResponseMemo.Lines.Add(Format('Response Code: %d', [LHTTP.ResponseCode]));
        ResponseMemo.Lines.Add(Format('Response Text: %s', [LHTTP.ResponseText]));
        ResponseMemo.Lines.Add(E.ErrorMessage);
        ShowMessage('HTTP Failure');
      end;
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        ResponseMemo.Lines.Add(E.ClassName);
        ResponseMemo.Lines.Add(E.Message);
        ShowMessage('Unknown Error');
      end;
    end;
  finally
    LHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

**UPDATE**: that being said, the [API documentation](https://www.routexl.com/blog/api/#post-tour) shows the following curl example:

> Get an unoptimized route using cURL:
>
> ```
> curl \
> --url https://api.routexl.com/tour/ \
> --user <username>:<password> \
> --data 'locations=[{"address":"1","lat":"52.05429","lng":"4.248618"},{"address":"2","lat":"52.076892","lng":"4.26975"},{"address":"3","lat":"51.669946","lng":"5.61852"},{"address":"4","lat":"51.589548","lng":"5.432482"}]&skipOptimisation=true'
> ```

That example DOES translate to the above Delphi code, per the [curl documentation](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-d):

> -d, --data
>
> (HTTP MQTT) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Compare to [-F, --form](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-F).

With the exception of one detail - when sending an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request with the `hoForceEncodeParams` option enabled, `TIdHTTP.Post()` will percent-encode the `[]`, `{}`, `"`, `:`, and `,` characters in the JSON in `%HH` format.  But the API's [Javascript and PHP examples](https://github.com/routexl/RouteXL-API-Connector) on GitHub are not doing that encoding, they send the JSON as-is.  So, if it turns out the API server does not like that encoding, then simply disable the `hoForceEncodeParams` option:

```pascal
LHTTP.HTTPOptions := [];
```

Comment: I'm using your code. Now I'm getting the error "EIdSocketError Socket Error # 10054 Connection reset by peer.". I analyzed my working JavaScript code to see if I can determine what could cause this. Removing this line `httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');` from my JS program causes this error "No input found". Also, my JavaScript did require a check on the ReadyState prior to handling the server response. The only other potential issue I see is the username:password. Is it okay to have that as two separate lines without the semicolon?

Comment: If I run the check for the `OpenSSLVersion();` before the POST, I get OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017.

Comment: To eliminate the JSON in the request you can add the `responseFromServer := IdHTTP1.Get('https://api.routexl.com/v2/status/Hello+world');` in place of the POST.

Comment: But by doing that, you are not replicating the Javascript's behavior anymore.  What EXACTLY does the server *expect* you to send to it?

Comment: The API requires username and password using Basic Authentication over HTTPS. You're correct, I just thought that may simplify things, but I'll stay with the POST example.  [Here's a link to API doc](https://www.routexl.com/blog/api/)

Comment: `Basic` authentication is most easily handled by using `TIdHTTP.Request.UserName/Password` and `TIdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication=True`. As for the API, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Okay, I've disabled the `hoForceEncodeParams` by adding the line `LHTTP.HTTPOptions := [];` as suggested, but I'm still getting the error "EIdSocketError Socket Error # 10054 Connection reset by peer.". Do I need to encode the username:password using the method my original code shows?

Comment: The server is forcibly disconnecting your client. Since the request is over HTTPS, the server probably doesn't like your client's TLS handshake, before the HTTP request is even transmitted. I would suggest using a packet sniffer, like Wireshark, to compare Javascript's TLS handshake to `TIdHTTP`'s TLS handshake to see how they differ. If I had to guess, since you are using Delphi XE6, you are probably also using an older Indy which doesn't support TLS's SNI extension. Most TLS 1.2 servers require SNI nowadays. Indy has supported client-side SNI for 5 years now, 2 years after XE6's release.

Comment: Okay, I've ported the app over to my Delphi 10.4 and Indy (v10.6.2.0) platform, but I'm still getting the same error. As you suspected my JavaScript apps packets show differently than the Delphi VCL apps packets for the TLS Handshake.  Delphi/Indy is using TLS v1.0 and my JavaScript appears to be using TLS v1.2. Is this due to v10.6.2.0, or if not how do I fix?

Comment: The code I gave you earlier should already be enabling TLS 1.2 if the server supports TLS 1.2. Indy uses dynamic negotiation when multiple TLS versions are specified in the SSLIOHandler's `SSLVersions` property. This allows client and server to negotiate the highest version they both support. But, if the server does not allow negotiation, then you will have to change the code to connect with just `SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2]` and if that fails then reconnect with just `SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_1]` and so on.

Comment: Just to be sure I wasn't missing something I recreated the whole project. I'm using "ssleay32.dll" file version: 1.0.2.14 with Windows 32-bit as the target platform. In the WireShark packet list section, the Delphi app Client Hello Handshake is showing as TLSv1 but the JavaScript app is showing TLSv1 and a Server  Hello as TLSv2. Even though the JavaScript app is showing as TLSv1 when you open the packet it appears to show a TLSv1.2 Record Layer which is showing TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello but with a version of 1.0. What could I be missing here?

Comment: OpenSSL 1.0.2.14 (1.0.2n) is a little old, the last version in the 1.0.2 series was 1.0.2.21 (1.0.2u). You can download updated DLLs from Indy's [OpenSSL-Binaries repo](https://github.com/IndySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries) on GitHub. And please don't just describe the issue, *edit your question* to add relevant details, screenshots, etc. Do you see an SNI hostname entry in the Javascript's TLS handshake? In Indy's handshake?

Comment: No, I only see "tls.handshake.extensions_server_name_type (0) and tls.handshake.extensions_server_name api.routexl.com". I don't know if that helps, but I updated the question and more detail and provided screenshots.

Comment: That is the SNI extension that I was referring to. So, you see that in the Javascript handshake, but not in the Indy handshake, right? Did you update your OpenSSL DLLs to 1.0.2u yet?

Comment: No, I see that in BOTH the JavaScript and Delphi app. What I see different is the `TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello` in JavaScript vs. `TLSv1 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello` when executing Delphi app. Why might that be different? Also, I did update the OpenSSL DLLs to 1.0.2u and I noticed that it takes longer to run possibly due to what appears to be a retransmission going on.

Comment: Additionally, I reached out to support for the API. They updated their service to require TLS 1.2 for all HTTPS connections, as previous versions have been deprecated. As a result any software running older insecure versions of TLS, may have connection problems such as socket error and connection reset. So how do I update Indy to use the current TLS v1.2 protocol?

Comment: @Hackbrew I already told you earlier how to do that. Simply change `SSLVersions` to just `[sslvTLSv1_2]` by itself.

Comment: I modified the title of the question to clarify and updated the code. Sorry, I should have indicated that I tried that `LHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];` modification yesterday with no change in result. With that change, it's still using TLS v1.0.

Comment: @Hackbrew I have rolled back your edit to your question, as it completely invalidated my answer.  I posted your edit as an update underneath the original question.

Comment: The server is closing the connection as soon as TIdHTTP sends its SSL/TLS "Client Hello" packet becuase it no longer support TLS 1.0. Althoguh I've configured the TIdHTTP to enable only TLS 1.2 `LHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2]; `, it ends up sending a TLS 1.0 hello instead. It appears something is causing OpenSSL to downgrade to TLS 1.0. Could this be a parameter in TidHTTP that's causing this or does Indy just not support this feature yet? Thank you for the edits Remy!

Comment: @Hackbrew you updated the DLLs, but did you also update Indy itself, like I suggested earlier? The version that shipped with XE6 is old, predating changes made to support TLS 1.2 (client-side SNI, default cipher list, etc). I'm guessing the latter in particular is your issue. IIRC, Indy used to enable only TLS 1.0 ciphers by default. You can update the `CipherList` property to enable TLS 1.2 ciphers. But the lack of SNI support is going to be a problem.

Comment: @RemLebeau - I'm using the version of Indy that came bundled with Delphi (v10.6.2.0) 10.4. Doesn't my Indy v10.6.2.0 have support for `sslvTLSv1_2` (TLS 1.2)?

Comment: @Hackbrew Yes, it does, and the other changes I mentioned. So it should be working. Using `SSLVersions=[sslvTLSv1_2]` *forces* only TLS 1.2, via OpenSSL's [`TLSv1_2_client_method()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/TLSv1_2_client_method.html) function. Its documentation says: "*A TLS/SSL connection established with these methods will only understand the TLSv1.2 protocol. **A client will send out TLSv1.2 client hello messages** and will also indicate that it only understand TLSv1.2. A server will only understand TLSv1.2 client hello messages.*"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228223/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-hackbrew).

Comment: As mentioned the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.IsOpenSSL_TLSv1_2_Available()` returns true. What in Indy or OpenSSL would be downgrading this to TLS v1.0?

Comment: I finally found the issue. The line `responseFromServer := IdHTTP1.Post('https://api.routexl.com/tour', sl);` should be `responseFromServer := LHTTP.Post('https://api.routexl.com/tour', sl);`. Then it works - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can change declaration of the `sLog: String` to `sLog: TStrings`. Then in the `onCreate` instantiate the `sLog := TStringList.Create` and then later in code `sLog.Text := Base64.Encode(s);`.

So,

```
var
  MainForm: TMainForm;
  ss: TStringStream;
  s, sFile : String;
  sLog: TStrings;
  Base64: TBase64Encoding;
  Txt: TextFile;
```

```
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  sLog := TStringList.Create;
  // Assign JSON to TStringStream
  ss := TStringStream.Create('locations= [{"address":"Test1","lat":"52.05429","lng":"4.248618"},{"address":"Test2","lat":"52.076892","lng":"4.26975"},{"address":"Test3","lat":"51.669946","lng":"5.61852"},{"address":"Sint-Oedenrode, The Netherlands","lat":"51.589548","lng":"5.432482"}]', TEncoding.UTF8);
  // Base64 encode username and password string to satisfy API for "Authorization", "Basic " + sLog);
  s := 'username:password';
  Base64 := TBase64Encoding.Create(20, '');
  sLog.Text := Base64.Encode(s);
end;
```

Comment: This answer does *absolutely nothing* to address any of the OP's issues at all. Not why OpenSSL is failing to load. Not why the JSON will not be sent to the server. Not why user authentication will fail. All you did was fix the input to `TIdHTTP.Post()` to use `TStringList` instead of `String` - which is the correct thing to do for sending an `application/x-www-webform-urlencoded` request, but the `TStringList` is still being with the completely wrong data (user credentials instead of JSON).

Comment: @RemyLebeau, so sorry, I was focused on the `The code below is giving me the error:` line in the post, so I tried to give the explanation for that. I'll try better next time.