# Cannot download a file from Amazon CDN programmatically

Tags: c++, delphi, ssl, winapi

I use URLDownloadToFile to download file from a URL. Normally it works well.

However, when I try to download a file from Amazon CDN, it will always fail.

The URL is: https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/dexr.exe, I can manually download from Chrome or FireFox without problems.

My code is:

```
    //  Delete the cache before calling URLDownloadToFile
    DeleteUrlCacheEntry(strURL);

    HRESULT hr;
    
    hr = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, strURL, strFileName, 0, NULL);
    
    if (hr == INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE)
        hr = hr;

    if (hr != S_OK)
    {
        _com_error err(hr);

        _tprintf(_T("Error in download: %s.\r\n"), err.ErrorMessage());
    }

    IStream* stream;
    hr = URLOpenBlockingStream(0, LPCTSTR(strURL), &stream, 0, 0);

    if (hr != S_OK)
    {
        _com_error err(hr);

        _tprintf(_T("Error in download: %s.\r\n"), err.ErrorMessage());
    }

    return  (hr == S_OK);
```

The result is below:

```
Error in download: Unknown error 0x800C0005.
Error in download: Unknown error 0x800C0005.
```

As the return error is unknown error, I even cannot know how to fix it.

**Update**

I try to use the codes in [Downloading a file in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506251/downloading-a-file-in-delphi) to download the file.

My code is:

```
function DownloadFile(const strURL: string; const strFileName: string): Boolean;
var
  IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
  http : TNetHTTPClient;
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
  Url, FileName: String;
begin
  Url := 'http://www.rejbrand.se';
  Filename := 'download.htm';

  IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  http := TNetHTTPClient.Create(nil);
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    //IdHTTP1.Get(strURL, Stream);
    http.Get(strURL, stream);
    Stream.SaveToFile(strFileName);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
    IdHTTP1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

When using TIdHTTP, I get the following exception:

```
Project DLVerify.exe raised exception class EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError with message 'Error connecting with SSL.
error:1409442E:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert protocol version'.
```

When using TNetHTTPClient, I get the following exception:

```
Project DLVerify.exe raised exception class ENetHTTPClientException with message 'Error sending data: (12175) A security error occurred'.
```

So it seems no codes can download from the URL.

**Update 2**

I try to change TLS to 1.2 and 2.0, both all fails with the same result:

```
function DownloadFile1(const strURL: string; const strFileName: string): Boolean;
var
  LHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  responseFromServer, sWhichFail, sVer :string;
    Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  //ResponseMemo.Clear;

  LHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(LHTTP);
    LHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvSSLv2, sslvSSLv23, sslvSSLv3, sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2];
    LHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
    LHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
    LHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;

    LHTTP.IOHandler := LHandler;
    LHTTP.AllowCookies := True;

       Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    //IdHTTP1.Get(strURL, Stream);
    LHTTP.Get(strURL, stream);
    Stream.SaveToFile(strFileName);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
    LHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Update 3:

Using

```
LHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2];
```

And get a little different result:

```
Project DLVerify.exe raised exception class EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError with message 'Error connecting with SSL.
error:140740BF:SSL routines:SSL23_CLIENT_HELLO:no protocols available'.
```

Comment: `URLDownloadToFile` is notoriously buggy and lacks decent error reporting. Best not to use it at all. Use the WinInet/WinHTTP API instead, or a 3rd party library like libcurl.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Thank you. I just tried other methods but also fail. I have updated the post accordingly.

Comment: You didn't provide your code for the other methods, but the Indy error message is pretty self-explanatory: `tlsv1 alert protocol version`. It means you are connecting to the server using the wrong SSL/TLS version. You are likely connecting with TLS v1.0 whereas the server likely requires at least TLS v1.2. When using `TIdHTTP`, be sure to assign an `SSLIOHandler` to it and configure it for appropriate TLS  versions.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you. I Have updated my post with the codes. Do you know a good sample on using SSLIOHandler  with TIdHTTP, I try to find but no good one.

Comment: @RemyLebeau posted an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/65971711/62576 which is a very complete and thorough example.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Try to set TLS to 1.2, 2.0, etc. all fails with the same result.

Comment: @alancc DO NOT enable `sslvSSLv2` or `sslvSSLv3`, they are outdated and no longer secure, nobody uses them anymore. Use ONLY `sslvTLSv1..sslvTLSv1_2`. That being said, which versions of Delphi and Indy are you using? Are they up-to-date? If you are using an old version, perhaps you are using a version of Indy that didn't support TLS's SNI extension yet, which many TLS servers require nowadays. Hard to say without knowing your actual setup

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I am using the latest version of Delphi(11.3 Alexandra). I try to use sslvTLSv1..sslvTLSv1_2 but get the same error, if using sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2, then the result is a bit different, see update.

Comment: Use `SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2]`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, This will produce the same result "Project DLVerify.exe raised exception class EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError with message 'Error connecting with SSL.
error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'."

Answer (score 1):

No issue with `TIdHTTP` (Indy 10.6.2.0) that is shipped with Delphi 11 Update 2 (28.0.46141.0937)

```
implementation

uses
  IdHTTP, IdSSLOpenSSL;

procedure Download;
var
  http: TIdHTTP;
  ssl: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
  //ShowMessage(http.Version);
  http := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    ssl := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(http);
    ssl.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];

    http.IOHandler := ssl;

    http.Get('https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/dexr.exe', ms);
    ms.SaveToFile('c:\temp\dexr.exe');
  finally
    ms.Free;
    http.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The openssl libs are 1.0.2u (1.0.2.21).

Same goes for `THTTPClient`, no issue:

```
implementation

uses
  System.Net.HttpClient;

procedure Download2;
var
  http: THTTPClient;
  ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
  http := THTTPClient.Create;
  ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    http.Get('https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/dexr.exe', ms);
    ms.SaveToFile('c:\temp\dexr.exe');
  finally
    ms.Free;
    http.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I use your code but still get the error. How to check openssl libs version? I am using Embarcadero® Delphi 11 Version 28.0.48361.3236 (Update 3) with Indy 10.6.2. It seems that I need to install openssl lib to make it work?

Comment: you may use this libs - https://github.com/IndySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries