# How to use TIdHTTP to get json dynamically in code with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, indy, http-get

When I do a GET request to "https://api.github.com/users/octocat" in Postman, then it works:

[image: Postman GET]

But If I try to do it in Delphi using `TIdHTTP` using the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  var apiURL := 'https://api.github.com/users/octocat';
  try
    var IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
    try
      var jsonResponse := IdHTTP.Get(apiURL);

      Memo1.Lines.Text := jsonResponse;
    finally
      IdHTTP.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage('Error: ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Then I get an error:

> Project raised exception class EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError with message 'Error connecting with SSL. error:1409442E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version'

What does this mean and/or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Crosspost from WhatsApp & Telegram. Was answered already

Comment: How does the image clarify or assist your question concerning the Delphi `TIdHTTP` component? Please consider that people may use SO via phones ot other devices with rather small displays.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` for `https`. Keep in mind you need the openssl libraries.

```
implementation

uses
  Idhttp, IdSSLOpenSSL;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  var apiURL := 'https://api.github.com/users/octocat';
  try
    var IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
    try
      var ssl := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP);
      ssl.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];
      IdHTTP.IOHandler := ssl;

      var jsonResponse := IdHTTP.Get(apiURL);

      Memo1.Lines.Text := jsonResponse;
    finally
      IdHTTP.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage('Error: ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: ALL THAT for a simple request? Why doesn't it handle the SSL automatically?

Comment: you could also use the `System.Net.HttpClient.THTTPClient` that's a wrapper for winhttp that uses the schannel.dll - for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77335407/cannot-download-a-file-from-amazon-cdn-programmatically/77346070#77346070 @alcalde

Comment: @alcalde [actually, it does](https://www.indyproject.org/2014/12/22/new-https-functionality-for-tidhttp/) (sort of).  But, `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` still [defaults to TLS v1.0](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/181), so you have to configure it manually (for the time being) if you want to use TLS v1.1 or v1.2.

Comment: Where can I get the openssl libraries? Why are they needed?

Comment: the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` uses openssl for `https` requests thus you need the binaries for that - https://github.com/IndySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries - for plain http they are not needed